# Comparing spectral sequences with different coefficients

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, abelian-groups, spectral-sequences

Several spectral sequences coming from geometry have a "degree of freedom" in choosing the coefficients (say an abelian group $A$). This applies fo example to the Serre spectral sequence and to the spectral sequence of cosimplicial spaces.

Is there a way of comparing the spectral sequences of different coefficients? This should be a generalization of the universal coefficient theorem (that applies to the early pages, but then gets somehow "lost" when turning pages).

If you also have a reference for this, it would be great.

Comment: I don't know how general you intend for things to be, as a spectral sequence generally won't have 'coefficients'. In the situation you are envisioning, would the Zeeman Comparison Theorem be useful?